# In linking, what is the difference between run-time addresses and the addresses in the .text (machine code) section of a relocatable object file?

Tags: linker, runtime, elf

I am learning about linking right now (self-taught) and I am having some trouble understanding some concepts.

After the preprocessing, compilation, and assembly of a source code file, you got a relocatable object file with an ELF format (WLOG). In this ____.o file, there is a .text section that contains the machine code of the individual source code.

Does this machine code correspond to the run-time addresses of the code that is in the input file? Like if the machine code where to run (assuming no unresolved external references) would the runtime profile of the code match the machine code here?

If this is true, is it safe to say that symbol references in this code are pointing to the runtime address of their corresponding symbols?

I need to know this so that I can better understand the linking process which happens directly after this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this machine code correspond to the run-time addresses of the code that is in the input file?

No.

It can't, because the code in a single `.o` file *doesn't* know what *other* object files will be linked into the main executable. Imagine `foo.o` saying "I want to be at address 0x123000", and `bar.o` saying "I want to be at address 0x123004". They clearly can't be both at the same address.

The "final" runtime addresses are determined by the *linker*, which collects all the different `.o` files, resolves references between them, and lays out the final executable in memory. (Even this isn't a complete story, as shared libraries and position-independent executables complicate the answer more.)

Comment: Ok but suppose that there is a single .o file that is being turned into an executable. Does the linker still do work then?

Comment: @pewpew_beepboop Yes, it does.